# Py2Neo Label Indexing

Tags: py2neo

I have a dataset containing words and documents associated with those words. I would like to set labels on them to separate them into these two categories. I was able to create the labels by doing this:

```
if not "Social Words" in graph_db.node_labels:
    neo4j.Schema.create_index(graph_db.schema, "Social Words", "word")

if not "Documents" in graph_db.node_labels:
    neo4j.Schema.create_index(graph_db.schema, "Documents", "url")
```

The problem is that I need to enforce uniqueness on the "word" and "url" fields. I am adding the nodes & labels as follows

```
doc,= graph_db.create({"url": url})
doc.add_labels("Documents")
```

My questions are :

1. Is there a way to add the node to the label index by using get_or_create
2. Does the py2neo api have a way to enforce uniqueness on the label index
3. Is there a better way to do all this. The documentation is a little fuzzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. No because there is no need to explicitly add a node to a schema index - these are included automatically when the label is present.
2. Py2neo does not have specific functions to support unique constraint management.
3. You could use Cypher for this instead (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-constraints.html#constraints-create-uniqueness-constraint)